# Creating a directory in AppData after launching my application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am working on an application developed in C # .net WPF, I wanted to know how to make every launch of my application,

1. Detect if there is an "Affaires" directory in "%AppData%\Roaming\N.O.E" and, if not, create the directory.
2. Detect if there is an "Affaires" directory in "C:\N.O.E" and, if there is, prompt the user if they want to move the directory to AppData. If yes, move the directory.

The installation is done with an administrator account.

Should the detection code for my application be in the class "App.XAML.cs"?

Code of the method that launches the application is:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException +=
        new 

        try
        {
            // Créé le répertoire des traces s'il n'existe pas déjà
            string cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string logPath = Path.Combine(cwd, "log");
            if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
            }
            // Log4Net configuration
            FileInfo log4NetConfig = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(cwd, 
            "Log4net.config"));
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4NetConfig);

            // Récupère la version de l'application
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = 
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Version version = assembly.GetName().Version;

            UpdateService.CheckingForUpdates();

            Log.Info("Démarrage de l'application " + 
            OtherHelper.GetAppSetting("NomApplication", "N.O.E") + " 
            version " + version);

            ConfigService.InitializeConfigPathAndModificationDate();

            TagService.InitializeReferential();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           ////////
        }

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending which AppData folder you need, you can retrieve the folder you need using `Environment.GetFolderPath()`.

So, to check for directory "Affaires" in AppData\Roaming\N.O.E create it if it doesn't exist, for example:

```
string appDataLocalPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string affairesDirPath = appDataRoamingPath + "\\N.O.E.\\Affaires";

if(!Directory.Exists(affairesDirPath))
{
    DirectoryInfo affairesDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(affairesDirPath);
    //Do anything else you need to with the directory here.
}
```

If you only need to create the directory without doing anything else with it, then you can simple use `Directory.CreateDirectory(affairesDirPath);`; it will not create the directory if it already exists.

For your other directory, you can do the following:

```
string affairesDirPath = "C:\\N.O.E.\\Affaires";

if(Directory.Exists(affairesDirPath))
{
    //Move the directory
}
```

Comment: thank you for your return, I also wanted to move the directory "Affaires" with these subdirectories of

"C: \\ N.O.E. \\ Affaires" to% AppData% \ Roaming \ NOE \ Affaires ".

I used System.IO.Directory.Move (file, businessFolder) but it did not work.

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error? Was it able to find the directory before attempting to move it?

Comment: I used this code and it works:   DirectoryInfo dirInf = new DirectoryInfo(affairesFolder);

foreach (var subdir in dirs)
                        {
                            string temppath = Path.Combine(affairesFolder, subdir.Name);

                            if (!Directory.Exists(temppath))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Directory.Move(subdir.FullName, temppath);
                                }

Comment: @Ali Great! If my answer helped you out, please sure to mark it as the answer and give it a vote, please :)